# Why is there an empty VirtualDrive folder (231 GB) in C:\ProgramFiles\Asus folder in my Asus Strix Laptop?

Tags: asus-laptop, asus, virtual-drive

I was trying to make space in my C drive because it is almost always full. While checking I saw a folder in path C:\ProgramData\ASUS. The folder name is VirtualDrive. It is an empty folder(I checked "show hidden files" option and it was active). This folder is taking almost half of my total C drive space. I am not able to show the image because I am new.

Can anyone please tell me if I can delete this folder or not?

Comment: Open a command prompt in the directory. Use the command `dir /a-h /a-s` to know everything thats in it.

Comment: And second thing, you can still attach image. Once you do, we'll edit it and make it visible.

Comment: According to ASUS, you can try restarting your pc. See this link for more information: https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?117546-Shadow-Drive-ate-60Gb-of-my-G531GU-SSD-storage-nowhere-to-be-found